# How to liberate propylthiouracil

Tags: organic-chemistry, purification

Two substances undergo a reaction that gives off propylthiouracil and another compound as products.

Is there an additional compound I could throw into that sludgy product to strain off the $\ce{C9H17O6}$ such as that used in the [Miller Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_process), but instead would leave a clear propylthiouracil for my use? The chemical reaction is given below:

$\ce{2 C11H19NO6 + C3H6OS -> C7H10N2O6 + 2 C9H17O6}$

Comment: Does it have to be a chemical reaction/destruction like the Miller Process or would something like a separation process be acceptable?  Have you tried anything along these or other lines?

Comment: @airhuff Anything at all is OK. As long as the resulting products have different viscosities. As to whether I have tried anything along those lines, none of the compounds I can think leaves the prothiouracil unaffected i.e adding an aqueous sodium hydroxide solution but that breaks the propythiouracil into ammonia, sodium thiocyanate and another compound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/propylthiouracil#section=Melting-Point/), propylthiouracil has the following solubility properties:

> 1 part dissolves in about 900 parts water at 20 deg C, in 100 parts
>   boiling water, in 60 parts ethyl alc, in 60 parts acetone; ***practically
>   insol in ether, chloroform, benzene (emphasis mine)***; freely sol in aq soln of ammonia
>   and alkali hydroxides.

I would start with a small amount of your "sludgy" product. Stir it with ether as a first choice, chloroform as a second, for a while and see first of all whether you really get multiple phases or if just forms a less viscous sludge.  In a perfect world, after letting the solution set you would see the white propylthiouracil solid settle out at the bottom, with a sludge-discolored solvent layer on top.  If you see anything resembling this, then I would pursue this technique with more thorough stirring/shaking, maybe centrifuging to get better settling of your product, then further rinsing your product on filter paper with a vacuum flask, etc.  Try the other solvents if available if ether doesn't work.  The success/failure of this approach depends on the solubility of the sludgy stuff in the solvent.  It may fail, it may not give the purity you need, it may work wonderfully, but it is a cheap and simple way to test a method with a reasonable probability of success.